# Edittext to String

Tags: android, android-edittext

On the Android I'm trying to turn an `Edittext` to a string. The `toString()` method doesn't work, playerName is null when I print it out. Are there any other ways to turn an edittext to a string?

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setMessage("Your Name");
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                playerName = input.getText().toString();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the alertdialog looks fine, but maybe the error is located in the rest of the code. You have to keep in mind that you are not able to use the var playerName just beneth the show() of the dialog, if you want to print out the name you should do this with a runnable wich you call here:

```
      static Handler handler = new Handler();

      [.......]

      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            playerName = input.getText().toString();
            handler.post(set_playername);

      }

      [.......]

     static Runnable set_playername = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
        //printout your variable playerName wherever you want
    }
  };
```

edit to clarify:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setMessage("Your Name");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            playerName = input.getText().toString();
            //call a unction/void which is using the public var playerName
        }
    });
    alert.show();
    // the variable playerName is NULL at this point
```

Comment: I'm trying to save the value to a variable, so if I declare another variable before alert.show() to hold it, would that work?

Comment: the general problem is, that alert.show() did not pause the executen of the calling void or function. The code beneth the show() will be executet immediatly and is not waiting for the OK. If you want to use the variable, you are able to store the value into a public variable, but you only will be able to use it in other voids/function not in the dialog calling one (like in vb or c#). If you want to youse it immediatly you habe to call the using function in the onclick method of the dialog and somtimes this has to be in a runnable

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you get the text out of a EditText

```
et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.resource_id_of_edittext);
String text = et.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 5):

`editText.getText().toString()` gives you a string

Comment: It should but playerName prints null.

Comment: checkit whether your playername textfield is properly initialized and assign to it?

Answer (score 2):

```
String mystring=input.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If `playerName` is declared as a `String`, you shouldn't need to cast it or anything. The `getText` method gives you a `CharSequence` which you can use as a `String`.

The issue is you're creating your `input` variable "from the scratch" so it will not make reference to any existing `View`. You should do something like:

```
EditText input = findViewById(R.id.player);
```

And then you can:

```
playerName = input.getText();
```